# Whats the proper way to propagate changes to child components?

Tags: react-native

Using react-native I don't understand, how I have to populate changes to nested structures.

I created a simple sample.
Parent owns a Button. When pressed, the clickcount within the parent will be increased.
How do I achieve that Child' clickcount will also be increased? (in my real world scenario I want specific childs to be re-rendered. I understand that I have to change some state therefore)

**Parent**

```
var React = require('react');
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        clickcount: this.props.clickcount,
      }

      child = (<Child clickcount={this.state.clickcount}/>);
  }

  handlePress() {
      console.log('Parent handlePress');
      this.increment();
  }

  increment() {
      this.setState({clickcount: this.state.clickcount+1});
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Parent {this.state.clickcount}</Text>
      
        <Button
                    title="OK"
                    onPress={() => this.handlePress()}
                />
     </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

**Child**

```
var React = require('react');
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        clickcount: this.props.clickcount,
      }
  }

  handlePress() {
      console.log('Child handlePress');
      this.increment();
  }

  increment() {
      this.setState({clickcount: this.state.clickcount+1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Child {this.state.clickcount}</Text>

     </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Currently, after 3x click the output looks like:

Parent 3
Child 0

Comment: So one immediate thing that caught my attention is that you're setting clickcount in the constructor: you should be doing it in the render method or in some other method. For example, in your render() you might have const clickcount = this.props.clickcount

Comment: indeed, when I change that, it works without any other change

Comment: feel free to like my comment if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the increment function to the child so the parent owns the click count

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.increment}/>
        {this.props.clickCount}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clickCount: 0
  }
  
  increment = () => {
    this.setState({ clickCount: this.state.clickCount + 1 })
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <Child increment={() => this.increment()} clickCount={this.state.clickCount}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In your solution child got its own button. But I want to steer the child from the button in the parent.

Comment: You can render the Button with the parent and still pass the clickCount to the child through props